# Some images not showing up on iOS(ReactNative)

Tags: ios, react-native, mapbox, react-native-ios, mapbox-gl-js

I am facing an issue in a react-native application where some images are not showing up in **iOS**, however same images are being displayed on android. Is there any issue in the images? Please check both attached images below:

Image showing up on both android and ios:
[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11/static/path-2+4080ff-1(oxdjGu_ucA),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(11.25387620,43.77496190)/11.2538762,43.7749619,7/1024x1024?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11/static/path-2+4080ff-1(oxdjGu_ucA),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(11.25387620,43.77496190)/11.2538762,43.7749619,7/1024x1024?access_token=%5BACCESS_TOKEN%5D)
[image]

Image not showing up iOS:
[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11/static/path-2+4080ff-1(oeu|B_m%7D%60No~tcBrjci%60@),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(78.96288000,20.59368400),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(-95.71289100,37.09024000)/51.407439337712,80.48698662388,0/1024x1024?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11/static/path-2+4080ff-1(oeu%7CB_m%7D%60No%7EtcBrjci%60@),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(78.96288000,20.59368400),url-http%3A%2F%2Fdev.abc.com%2Fmpin1.png(-95.71289100,37.09024000)/51.407439337712,80.48698662388,0/1024x1024?access_token=%5BACCESS_TOKEN%5D)
[image]

Code I am using is:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native'
<Image
    style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
    source={{uri: imageUrl}}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
/>
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: might be related to image resolution

Comment: Which React-native version? And IOS version?

Comment: @rishikesh_07 here are versions details:

ReactNative: 0.62.0-rc.2
iOS: 14.4

Comment: @nazmul both are 1024x1024 in dimension and have same format(JPEG)